# How to crop images with rememberLauncherForActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-image, android-jetpack-compose

I'm launching **rememberLauncherForActivityResult()** to pick images from gallery from a composable function, but I can't crop the returned image.

**here's my code:**

```
val context= LocalContext.current
    val contract=ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    val launcher= rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = contract) {
        vm.pictures.add(it.toBitmap(context)!!)
    }
```

**how I launch it**

```
launcher.launch("image/*")
```

NOTE that I can't use an intent because I'm outside of the activity

Comment: "NOTE that I can't use an intent because I'm outside of the activity" -- have you [tried `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult)?